# Por que um parâmetro tem dois "const" na sua declaração?

Tags: c++, ponteiro, parâmetros, const

Estou lendo os tutoriais no site da lib OpenCV e durante a leitura vi a declaração de uma função com uma variável em um formato que nunca vi. Queria saber o que significa, declarar a variável desta forma. Segue a assinatura da função:

```
Mat& ScanImageAndReduceRandomAccess(Mat& I, const uchar * const table)
```

`const uchar * const table` sei que é um ponteiro para um `unsigned char`, mas nunca vi dois `const` sendo usado desta maneira! Esta é a minha dúvida: O que ele está querendo dizer?

Comment: Retirei a tag do OpenCV porque você poderia ter encontrado isso em qualquer biblioteca de qualquer lugar. O fato da assinatura ser assim não é algo particular ou específico do OpenCV.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
const uchar * const table
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Syntax/Const.c).

Objetos apontados são compostos por duas informações, um ponteiro e o dado propriamente dito. Por padrão ambos são mutáveis.

O primeiro `const` indica que o conteúdo apontado é constante e não pode ser mudado em condições normais. Mas isso por si só não quer dizer que não possa apontar para outro objeto completamente diferente.

O segundo `const` indica que o ponteiro também é constante e não pode ser mudado.

Então essa função recebe um argumento que é "garantido" que será só leitura.

Garantido é modo de dizer, há maneiras de subverter isso, embora não deveria.